# ApolloClient V3 infinite scroll goes up to the first item after fetchMore

Tags: reactjs, state, apollo, apollo-client, infinite-scroll

thanks for being out here! I am new to React and Apollo and will try my best to explain my situation.

Right now I implemented an 'infinite' scroll to my website with ApolloClient V3. This infinite scroll can be seen [here](https://hhwig-remote-vercel-jyc5ejbem.vercel.app/). As you try it out, you see that the whole page refreshes instead of just the data that gets added in `fetchMoreResult`.

I implemented it according to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dRk3bxEbS8&t=649s). In this video, you can see that it doesn't happen, the code stays at the bottom and showing an occasional spin.

Below I will show you my code:

I am using

```
const { data, error, loading, fetchMore, networkStatus } = useQuery(
GET_ALL_COUNTRIES_MAIN,
    {
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      variables: {
        offset: 0,
        limit,
      },
    }
  );

  if (!data || !data.globaldatasortednew) return <CircularProgress />;
```

To pull my data. Then I set a waypoint to fetchMore like this:

```
 return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Grid container={true} justify="center" spacing={2}>
        {data.globaldatasortednew.map((country, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={country.countryid}>
              {index === data.globaldatasortednew.length - 5 && (
                <Waypoint
                  onEnter={() =>
                    fetchMore({
                      variables: {
                        limit: 30,
                        offset:
                          data.globaldatasortednew[
                            data.globaldatasortednew.length - 5
                          ].countryid,
                      },
                    }).then((fetchMoreResult) => {
                      setLimit(
                        data.globaldatasortednew.length +
                          fetchMoreResult.data.globaldatasortednew.length
                      );
                    })
                  }
                />
              )}
      </Grid>
      {networkStatus === 3 && <CircularProgress />}
```

On mobile phones, this causes the data to scroll back to the top which is quite inconvenient? How to prevent this and don't let the whole Grid re-render?

Once more, thanks, and I hope I was clear enough in describing!

Answer (score 0):

For people who have the same problem, for me it was apollo cache policy issue.

Remove `cache-and-network` from fetchPolicy to be good ;)

Comment: What policy did you use instead of cache-and-network?